# Override the path of my API in Springfox Swagger

Tags: spring-rest, springfox

I am using Spring REST with Springfox Swagger, and I had a method such as

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/my-methd")
@ApiOperation(value = "My method")
```

and all was working fine.

Now I notice there is a **spelling mistake** in the path. I already have clients using the existing API, so I would like to support both the old and new versions, but only have the new versions show up in the documentation.

I can correct it like follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = {
   "/my-methd",  // Spelling mistake, deprecated
   "/my-method"  // To be used by new software
})
@ApiOperation(value = "My method")
```

However, **both the old and new spelling** show up in the Swagger docs.

I want both to work, but **only the new spelling** to show up in the Swagger docs.

The `@ApiOperation` has the facility to override the HTTP method, and many other things, but seemingly not the path.

Is there anything I can do here?

(I can't even mark the old method as "deprecated" in the docs, as the docs come from the method annotation, which is shared between the two paths.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to just create a new separate method, one with the misspelled RequestMapping "/my-methd", and one for the correct one "/my-method".
Then it's easy to mark the misspelled one as deprecated.
Also this way you can put proper comments in the code, so in the future it's easier to maintain / remove.